# Querying New Relic with GraphQL in Python

Tags: python, rest, graphql, newrelic

I just started using GraphQL with New Relic and I'm having troubles trying to pass variables to the GraphQL query.
I need to retrieve the NR Synthetics monitors GUID's based on their names, for which I thought of searching for the entity and then get the guid from the query response.
This is my piece of code containing the query:

```
    query = '''
    query($query: String!) {
      actor {
        entitySearch(query: $query) {
          results {
            entities {
              guid
            }
          }
        }
      }
      variables { query: "name LIKE \u0027MYMONITORNAME\u0027" }
    }'''
```

Then I call the NR API:

```
    my_response = requests.get(
    url=my_url,
    headers=header,
    json={"query": query}
)
```

And I get this back:

```
{'errors': [{'locations': [{'column': 30, 'line': 12}], 'message': 'syntax error before: "\\"name LIKE \'MYMONITORNAME\'\\""'}]}
```

I've tried many escape sequences, double quotes/single quotes/no quotes combinations but can't seem to nail the right format.
Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Sebastian

Comment: What you have shared here is a string. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Hi Dan, the string contains the GraphQL query, which I then send to the NR API as I have just added to the post. It's pretty basic though.

Comment: I might have found another way to do it by doing an NRQL query, but it implies parsing the query response, which is what GraphQL should help with:

nrql(query: "SELECT entityGuid from SyntheticCheck WHERE  monitorId =\'''' + mon_id["data"] + '''\'")

Not very elegant.